# Debye-Waller Factor in the case of isotropic fluctuations

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, scattering, phonons, x-rays

I am reading through Girvin & Yang Ch. 6 (pg. 91), they mention that the Debye-Waller factor
$$-2\Gamma(\vec{q})=-\langle\langle(\vec{q}\cdot\vec{u}_j)^2\rangle\rangle$$

(where the positions of atom j is given by $\vec{r}_j = \vec{R}_j+\vec{u}_j$, and $\vec{R}_j$ being a lattice vector and the averaging a thermal averaging) becomes takes the following form if we consider **isotropic fluctuations** of $\vec{u}_j$:
$$-2\Gamma(\vec{q})=-\frac{q^2}{Nd}\sum_j\langle\langle\vec{u}_j\cdot\vec{u}_j\rangle\rangle$$

$N$ is the number of lattice points and $d$ is the dimension of the system.

**I am not sure how the sum and the prefactors can come in, for this case.**